# How to call an extension function from an aspx file rather code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to call a function that returns color from hexa representation. How to do it.

Here is my code

`<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' BackColor='<%# Eval("ColorCode") %>'></asp:Label>`

I want to call it this way

`<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' BackColor='<%# Eval("ColorCode").ToString().ToColor() %>'></asp:Label>`

Currently it shows an error InvalidCastException because it returns string.
I have created an extension that gives Color and applies to string.
How to use it here.

This function is under other namespace where the page is.

```
    public static Color ToColor(this string originalColor)
    {
        return ColorTranslator.FromHtml(originalColor);
    }
```

Here is the error If I tries to call ToColor

**'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToColor' and no extension method 'ToColor' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: I have never tried it, but try Eval("ColorCode.ToColor")

Answer (score 4):

If `ToColor()` is in a different namespace than your current page, you will have to reference it from the top of your aspx page.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="ShantanuGupta" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eval returns an object, so your extension method won't work as it's on `string`, not `object`.

You can either:

- Change the extension method so that it operates on `object`, which is a *bad* idea, as not all objects are colours.
- Add a new function to your code behind called `ToColor` and call that.

For example

```
// In codebehind
protected Color ToColor(object originalColor)
{
    return ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Convert.ToString(originalColor));
}

//in markup

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' BackColor="<%# ToColor(Eval("ColorCode")) %>"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: @Tom, that's why I didn't make it an extension method.

Comment: @Tom, Rob: What if I have either string or NULL stored in database. In that case how will it behave.

Comment: @Shantanu, I have no idea what you mean by that. The `ToColor` method will do whatever you choose to tell it to do. It's no different to writing it as an Extension method, so ultimately the question is "what do **you** want it to do?" =)